# Update Shiny's 'selectInput' dropdown with new values after uploading new data using fileInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that includes a number of dropdown selection boxes, the values of which are filled from reading an RDS file. The app also includes a fileInput function to upload new data. How can I change the values in the dropdown boxes to reflect the new data? Currently I can see that the data is uploaded, but the old data remains in the dropdown.

The data that should be uploaded is saved to a file using

```
saveRDS( data.frame(names=c("Jill","Jane","Megan")),"myDataFrame.rds")
```

In my app.R file, I first define the 'default' value of the data:

```
myDataFrame <- data.frame(names=c("Tom","Dick","Harry"))
```

The content of my `app.R` is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(
 fluidPage(
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',accept = ".rds"),
  selectInput("myNames","Names",myDataFrame$names),
  tableOutput('contents')
 )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) { return(myDataFrame) }
    readRDS(inFile$datapath)
  })
  })
```

The initial view of the application is as expected: both the dropdown and the table contain the 'default' names. Upon upload of my RDS file containing a new dataframe, the table changes (which is what I was looking for) but the dropdown values do not. How can I make the latter happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added reactive object `myData` that you have to use for table `contents`, but more importantly to update choices in `selectInput` (check `observe` and `updateSelectInput` part).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose file to upload", accept = ".rds"),
        selectInput("myNames","Names", ""),
        tableOutput("contents")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    myData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) {
            d <- myDataFrame
        } else {
            d <- readRDS(inFile$datapath)
        }
        d
    })

    output$contents <- renderTable({
        myData()
    })

    observe({
         updateSelectInput(session, "myNames",
                           label = "myNames",
                           choices = myData()$names,
                           selected = myData()$names[1])
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: No(t yet). The dropdown is now filled with the numbers 1, 2 and 3 - both before and after file upload.

Comment: @janverkade You're using exact code and same `myDataFrame`? Have you changed data.frames? I imagine row numbers having something to do with this.

Comment: Strange, because I'm not getting this (my shiny version is `shiny_1.0.3`).

Comment: An update from 0.14 to 1.0.3 fixed it alright ;) Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to riff off of @PoGibas' answer, I needed to load multiple list values for an app, here is a similar application using `reactiveValues` and `observeEvent` :

```
library(shiny)

# save a dummy RDS for loading
saveRDS(list(names=LETTERS,numbers=seq(10)),'dummy.rds')
# define initial values
myDataList <- list(names=c("Tom","Dick","Harry"), numbers=seq(5))

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose file to upload", accept = ".rds"),
    selectInput("myNames","Names", ""),
    selectInput("myNumbers","Numbers", ""),
    tableOutput("contents")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  md <- reactiveValues(
    names = myDataList$names,
    numbers = myDataList$numbers
  )

  observeEvent(input$file1,{
      d <- readRDS(input$file1$datapath)
      for (n in names(d)){
        md[[n]] <- d[[n]]
      }
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
   data.frame(data = c(md$names,md$numbers))
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "myNames",
                      label = "myNames",
                      choices = md$names,
                      selected = md$names[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, "myNumbers",
                      label = "myNumbers",
                      choices = md$numbers,
                      selected = md$numbers[1])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```